# Do createContext() and useReducer() receive the same 'initialState' object?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-context

Trying out typescript + react hooks + context api, I notice that both `createContext` and `useReducer` have required arguments for 'initialState'. It feels weird to define this once and pass the same object into both, which makes me wonder what the difference is.

Comment: `createContext` and `useReducer` have absolutely nothing to do with each other. Contexts and stores/reducers are different things entirely. There are some ways to use them together, but they should not be conflated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the difference?

Well, context is a special way to share values with a parent component to deeply nested children.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

`useReducer` is something else entirely, it's a way of managing React state with pure functions that transform state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

They have nothing to do with each other. They are used totally independently, although there are some scenarios where you would use them together, there is nothing inherent to React that links them together.

So, they need different `initialState` parameters because they are different systems, with different requirements, and different usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I'm confused by why `createContext` requires state then (see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24509#issuecomment-382213106), given that the state is passed into the provider element (perhaps using the return value from `useReducer`)

Comment: The value you pass to a context provider doesn't even need to be "state". It could literally be a `const` string, or a predefined number, or anything else. The `value` is just an abstract JavaScript "value" which can be anything. It just so happens that setting that value from some kind of state - whether it's `useState`, or class component `this.state`, or a redux store, or a `useReducer`, or whatever else - makes it more powerful and flexible.